# Group SQL outputs with same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, grouping

I'm trying to create a script that shows the openings of a store.
I want this openings to be listed below each others. If for example, Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday has the exact same opening time, I want it to be grouped like this:

---

Mon-Wed: 12:00-15:00

Thursday: 13:00-15:00

Friday: 10:00-18:00

Saturday: 12:00-18:00

Sunday: 14:00-18:00

---

It works fine when outputting weekday by weekday, but I cannot figure out, how to 'group' the weekdays, with the same opening time.

I have tried to use `if($time == $time)` but that didn't worked. I do not have any other ideas how to do it.

I don't want to get the weekday names from the table itself. That's why I've created the `$weekdays array` so that I can change the weekday name, directly in the code.

I also need to put the weekday names and the opening times in separate spans.

This is my SQL Table:

```
ID |     mon      |     tue      |     wed      |     thu      |     fri      |     sat      |     sun      
1    12:00-15:00    12:00-15:00    12:00-15:00    13:00-15:00    10:00-18:00    12:00-18:00    14:00-18:00
```

This is my current PHP code:

```
$get_openings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM openings WHERE NC_Id='1'");
while($days = mysql_fetch_array($get_openings)) {

   // Loads time only from database
   $mon = $days['mon'];
   $tue = $days['tue'];
   $wed = $days['wed'];
   $thu = $days['thu'];
   $fri = $days['fri'];
   $sat = $days['sat'];
   $sun = $days['sun'];

   $weekdays = array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thuesday','friday','saturday','sunday');
   $times = array($mon,$tue,$wed,$thu,$fri,$sat,$sun);

   $i = 0;
   foreach($times as $time) {

      while ($i <= 6) {

          if($time == "") {
              echo $weekdays[$i++].": "."Closed<br>";
          }

          else {
              echo $weekdays[$i++].": ".$time."<br>";
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks - Jesper

Comment: On a side note, you can remove your `while` statement and incrementing `$i` variables and use the key from your foreach: `foreach($times as $i => $time)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$previous_time = null;
$previous_day = null;
$consequetive = 0;
while($days = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_openings)) { // loop through your rows
    $days[''] = null;
    foreach ($days as $day => $time) { // loop through your fields
        if ($day != "id") { // skip the `id` field
            if ($previous_time !== $time) {
                echo $consequetive > 0 ? $previous_day : "";
                echo $previous_day ? ": " : "";
                echo $previous_time === "" ? "Closed" : $previous_time;
                echo $previous_day && $day ? "<br>" : "";
                echo $day;
                $consequetive = 0;
            }
            else {
                echo ++$consequetive == 1 ? " - " : "";
            }
            $previous_time = $time;
            $previous_day = $day;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But what if I wanted to have the full day name of the days which is not 'merged/grouped' together?

Answer (score 0):

1) define `$weekdays` outside the while-loop, since it doesn't change

2) define `$mon`, `$tue` ... and then collect them again in $times doesn't make sense. You can directly use the named array from the fetch statement.

```
$weekdays = array('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun');
$get_openings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM openings WHERE NC_Id='1'");

while($days = mysql_fetch_array($get_openings)) {

  $result = array();
  foreach($weekdays as $day){
    $time = $days[$day]==''?'closed':$days[$day];
    if(count($result)>0 and $result[0][1]==$time){
      $result[0][0] = substr($result[0][0],0,3) . '-' . $day;
    } else {
      array_unshift($result,array($day,$time));
    }
  }
  $result = array_reverse($result);
  /* add code to display $result here */
}
```

In each loop `$result` is an array of array containing the day names and the openning times. For Example: `array(array('mon-wed','12:00-15:00'),array('thu',...),...)`
    */